# Powershell command output parsing

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-cmdlet, airwatch

I currently am trying to get nslookup information.

I use the nslookup to find cisco umbrella information

```
nslookup -q=txt debug.opendns.com | select-string -Pattern "device"
```

My output shows as

```
Non-authoritative answer:

        "device 0xxxxyyyyyzzzzze"
```

but it is truly only outputting `device 0xxxxyyyyyzzzzze`, which is great.

However, is there a way to parse this information further so that it will only show the "0xxxxyyyyyzzzzze" part? The number letter sequence is always different. I would like this get this information into an MDM as custom variable so I can do remediation on devices without it.

Tried

```
nslookup -q=txt debug.opendns.com | select-string -Pattern "device" -Exclude "device"
```

Wasn't sure if this can' be done for text on the same line.
Trying to not sure the word "device" but show the rest of the text.

Comment: What about `Select-String '(?<=device\s)\S+' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }`, I can't get the same output as you so hard to tell

Comment: Thanks a lot @SantiagoSquarzon. 

I got 0xxxxyyyyyzzzzze" as the output.


I used this to get rid of the extra quotes at the end
nslookup -q=txt debug.opendns.com | Select-String '(?<=device\s)\S+' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value.trim('"') }

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better regex than the one in my comment, with this one there is no need to trim the last double-quote `"` from the string:

```bash
nslookup -q=txt debug.opendns.com | Select-String '(?<=device\s)[^"]+' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

See https://regex101.com/r/gdL46B/1 for details.